# VK iOS SDK для Swift

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю проект на Swift, подключил iOS SDK через cocoapods, когда пишу

```
import VK_ios_sdk
```

выдаёт ошибку

> no such module

Подскажите кто сталкивался, как решили данную проблему?

Comment: Вы либу в настройках проекта подключили? Возможно, нужно.

Comment: @AivanF. да, добавил в Linked Frameworks and Libraries: VK_ios_sdk.framework

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если правильно собирать решение с CocoaPods, то в `General` -> `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` должен появиться .a-файл библиотеки и .a-файл pods проекта, соответственно Tragets проекта Подов.

Answer (score 1):

После инсталляции pod запусти Build и после этого будет всего подхватываться. Так было у меня!

Answer (score -1):

После установки VK_SDK у вас в папке с проектом должен появиться файл со следующим названием *.xcworkspace. Нужно запустить его, после чего подключайте VK_sdk_ios.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]